# Why might an application fail to start on Windows 7 x64 with faulting module GDI32.dll?

Tags: windows-7, gdi, nsis

I'm attempting to run [NSIS.exe](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) on Windows 7 x64, but it's crashing on start, and leaving this in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: NSIS.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4b1ae3a1
Faulting module name: GDI32.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdb38
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000150cc
Faulting process id: 0x1320
Faulting application start time: 0x01ca932bed85dabf
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\NSIS.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
Report Id: 2b425403-ff1f-11de-9869-e9dacc29dd83
```

I've [opened a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2930312&group_id=22049&atid=373085) with NSIS, but I cant help but feel it could be a problem with my Windows installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned a simple rule with Microsoft products: if they do not work as expected, restart them or reboot the computer, and if they still don't work, DON'T PANIC and look online for a solution.

Comment: I always tell end users to reboot before they call me... Why do I never take my own advice? Ha...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the cause is, but restarting fixes this. Man I hate restarting...